# Method value's won't go to other scopes?

Tags: java, methods, jgrasp

I'm very very new, I'll try my best to word best I can (english is not my first language.) I hope my topic name is not confusing, right to the point.

```
 public static double dogTotalFee(double totalFee)//calculate total fee (without tax)
{
        double cost = 0.0;
        double weight = 0.0;
        int days = 0;

        cost = 0.7;          

        return totalFee = cost * weight * days;

 }//end dogTotalFee

 public static double dogTax(double totalTax)//calculate tax
 {double taxRate = 0.0;

  double totalFee = 0.0;

 return totalTax = totalFee * taxRate;

 }//end dogTax

  public static double dogTotalPrice(double totalPrice)
 {
  double totalFee = 0.0;
  double totalTax = 0.0;

  return totalPrice = totalFee + totalTax;
 }//end dogTotalPrice
```

These values show up as zero, and the calculations don't add up.

```
     totalFee = dogTotalFee(totalFee);

     totalTax = dogTax(totalTax);

     totalPrice = dogTotalPrice(totalPrice);
```

### lPrice);

I'm mostly doing the math in the methods, I just can't seem to get the values to transfer. Thank you

Comment: `return totalFee = cost * weight * days;` Back to the tutor/textbook/online tutorial for you.... Not to mention anything `* 0 == 0`.

Comment: Thank you @John3136,
I looked back, and I saw that I put the wrong values in, thank you!! I'm sorry again, I'm not trying to abuse this forum.